# Python function that saves output from the function into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, encryption, global-variables

This program is supposed to give the user input in order for the program to take that input and as an output release the encrypted text while saving the encrypted text in a list when the user inputs 'save'.
**The problem here is that when the user enters save it will only append the encrypted word of 'save' into the list.**

```
alph = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
        'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


def encrypt(text):
    global semi_crypt
    semi_crypt = ""

    for char in text:
        if char not in alph:
            semi_crypt = semi_crypt + char
        try:
            if char in alph:
                x = alph.index(char)
                semi_crypt = semi_crypt + alph[x + 3]
        except IndexError:
            if char == "x":
                semi_crypt = semi_crypt + 'a'
            elif char == "y":
                semi_crypt = semi_crypt + 'b'
            elif char == 'z':
                semi_crypt = semi_crypt + "c"
    return semi_crypt


print('''
This is Encrypto
''')
print('Type end to save when you are done')

while True:
    crypted_l = []
    message = input('Encrypt something: ')
    print(encrypt(message))
    crypted_l.append(encrypt(message))
    if message == 'save':
        print(f"{'Saved:'}{crypted_l}")
        break
```

Comment: Move `crypted_l = []` out of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `crypted_l` out of the loop, as follows:

```
crypted_l = []
while True:
    message = input('Encrypt something: ')
    print(encrypt(message))
    crypted_l.append(encrypt(message))
    if message == 'save':
        print(f"{'Saved:'}{crypted_l}")
        break
```